# Does ActionBar Sherlock cause problems with MediaRecorder?

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I have a problem using MediaRecorder to record video with ActionBar Sherlock.  I have a base app that sets up and records video files without any problem, but as soon as I add ABS, it stops working.

Right now I have a non-ABS app that can record video with no problems at all and the same app (in all other respects) with ABS that doesnt work.

Initialising the video recorder using the CAMCORDER settings gets through the MediaRecorder setup OK, but when I stop recording, I get a '-1' error in the logcat and the resulting .MP4 file has no audio or video track (although the file size looks OK).

If I try setting MediaRecorder with maunaul setups (i.e., format, frame rate, size etc), the setup keeps falling over at 'setVideoSource...CAMERA'.

Does anyone know if there's any reason why ABS would upset MediaRecorder this way?

Added 01/01/13:The application I'm working on is being upgraded from a photo-taking app to a video-recording app.  The preview for the camera was previously done with a ImageView frame, which works OK for providing an image preview, but not for use as the video preview on MediaRecorder.  For MediaRecorder, I needed to use a SurfaceView.  Once I switched to a SurfaceView, all was good!

Comment: OK, it's nothing to do with ActionBarSherlock - just a problem with my preview.

Comment: ok then please post some details of what went wrong it may help others and mark its as the answer..